# Re-factor old PRs

Tags: git, github

I have a PR that is like 1 year old and want to include it in my repo. Its like 100 commits since and the merge is grey (not automagically mergeable).

What are my options?

I could ask him to rebase and send a new PR (I doubt he will, he has not been active since then).

I thought about cloning his branch and trying to rebase but that would not be his PR. Can I transfer the PR to another branch then master?

Cannot either cherry-pick because it has conflicts and I don't know how to solve them :(

Any pointers would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking your collaborator for help may work - don't dismiss that just because.

Besides, the best would be to clone that branch, work on it, push it back (maybe even force-pushed) and then merge changes onto `master`. A big thanks to him in the PR comments would be enough to prevent him feeling you've dismissed his work/authorship - chances are he doesn't want the credit, anyway, but your project to move on :)